# Breeze fetch causing unmapped original values to be lost

Tags: breeze

I have a case where a **breeze entity loses it's `originalValues` for *unmapped properties* when that entity is fetched a second time.**

I know *why* this is happening I just don't think it should.

The `originalValues` are being cleared on the subsequent fetch because breeze sees that the entity is *not modified* and correctly merges in the incoming values from the server. However, my entity has unmapped properties that have changed and whose original values are stored in the `originalValues` hash. These are being cleared.

I can understand an argument that says this should be the behaviour with a `MergeStrategy` set to `OverwriteChanges`.

However, this **clearing of `originalValues` occurs with a `MergeStrategy` of `PreserveChanges`**. That behaviour I do not think is a good idea.

With a `MergeStrategy` of `PreserveChanges`, when an entity is considered unmodifed, etc, and the incoming values are merged in I do not think `originalValues` should be cleared.

Now there is a possible workaround by setting using a `MergeStrategy` of `SkipMerge`, however this causes problems as the entity is then never refreshed with incoming values.

So can this be behaviour be changed please?

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting use case ... one worth some serious reflection.

Let's walk through the semantics of merging query results when the `MergeStrategy` is "PreserveChanges".

First, some observations:

- Breeze does not change the `EntityState` when you change an unmapped property
- Breeze DOES preserve the pre-change value of an unmapped property in `OriginalValues`.

Let's consider how Breeze merges query results:

- *when the `EntityState` is in a changed state*, **all** properties (mapped and unmapped) are **preserved** even if a corresponding queried property value is different.
- *when the `EntityState` is "Unchanged"*, **all** properties (mapped and unmapped) are **replaced** by corresponding queried property values discovered in the query results payload.

> **Breeze does not support a *partial merge*. It will not overwrite some properties and preserve others.**

I don't know *for certain* why query processing clears `OriginalValues` (I say that without having looked into it yet or even confirmed that it does).  But I think it is doing the right thing.

Consider what it means when ***any*** property is merged into an unchanged entity. Suppose property `foo` was 1 before the query and the new queried value is 2.

Subsequently, we set `foo` to 3. What should the the "original value" be at that time? It should be 2, right? It shouldn't be 1. It should be the last value retrieved from the server.

It follows that after a merge, original values are implicitly identical to the entity's most current values. That is, if a property had a value in `OriginalValues`, it should be identical to the corresponding current value. And if the current value === the original value, we might as well remove that property from the `OriginalValues` ... which means clearing the `OriginalValues` for that property is harmless.

> **Because Breeze performs *full* merges (not *partial* merges), it follows that clearing the *entire* `OriginalValues` is consistent behavior.**

According to this line of reasoning - if you believe that mapped and unmapped properties should follow the same merge rules - Breeze is doing exactly the right thing.

Perhaps what you want is to treat a change to an unmapped property as a change to the `EntityState`.

I think we did that at one time in the past but we were persuaded that the `EntityState` should only reflect changes to **mapped** properties which are presumed to be the *persisted* properties.

It appears that you disagree, at least in your specific use case. I think (please confirm) that when you change an unmapped property, you want Breeze to treat the entity as "dirty".

Fortunately, you can handle this yourself. Add a handler to the `EntityManager.entityChanged` event and change the `EntityState` when something updates an unmapped property. You can do this broadly or selectively.

You'll have an uphill climb if you really seek different treatment of mapped and unmapped properties. We'll listen of course ... but you'll have to make one heck of a great argument.

You might get further by proposing something more general purpose such as a new `MergeStrategy` that supports a ***developer-defined custom policy***.

Maybe we'd extend the metadata such that you can specify a merge function that governs how Breeze merges properties for a given `EntityType`.  That would be cool.

It would be a significant new feature, requiring a ton of testing. I think it's going to take a lot of persuading to get that one on the board.

Comment: WRT setting entity dirty when unmapped property changes: for a calculated property (a value the server calculates and sends to the client and the server never consumes from the client) it makes no sense to change the value on the client. It seems fine if the entity is not set dirty. And since the server doesn't use the value, the entity does not need saving.  But, if it's possible that an unmapped property is used for the client to communicate to the server (is this allowed/possible?) then changing it should make the entity dirty.  Comes down to whether the property is readonly vs. read-write.